# LaTeX locally change equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

I want my document to look like this:

> Normal document text.
>
> equation             (1)
>
> **Definition** *Definition text.*
>
> equation         (D1)
>
> *More definition text.*
>
> Normal document text.
>
> equation      (2)
>
> More document text.

So the numbering changes inside the definition, and remains unaltered outside the definition.

Answer (score 21):

If you only want a temporary change, use the `\tag` command, loaded by the `amsmath` package. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Equation the first, normally numbered.
\begin{equation}
a=b+c
\end{equation}

A special equation.
\begin{equation}\tag{D1}
d=e+f
\end{equation}

A second, normally numbered equation.
\begin{equation}
g=h+i
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you use `\label` to reference the equations later, `\tag` doesn't have to have the same argument as `\label`. This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can define a new environment.

```
\newcounter{defcounter}
\setcounter{defcounter}{0}

.
.
.

\newenvironment{myequation}{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{D\thedefcounter}
\begin{equation}}
{\end{equation}}
```

And use it like

```
\begin{myequation}\label{myeq:one}
  a = b
\end{myequation}
```

You can use it any where and you get D1, D2 etc as the equation number.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{defcounter}
\setcounter{defcounter}{0}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\newenvironment{myequation}{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{D\thedefcounter}
\begin{equation}}
{\end{equation}}
%
\begin{document}
  Bbla bla
   \begin{equation}
     x = y
   \end{equation}
\begin{defn}
   bla bla
   \begin{myequation}\label{myeq:one}
     a = b
   \end{myequation}
   \begin{myequation}
     a = b
   \end{myequation}
\end{defn}
bla bla
   \begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
     x = yz
   \end{equation}
   \begin{myequation}
     a = b
   \end{myequation}

From equation~\ref{myeq:one} and~\ref{eq:one}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm not really sure if one would want to do this, but with the following implementation it will be easy to revert to a unique numbering scheme. The `equation` counter is changed inside the `defn` environment, so there's no need to change the coding style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % just to show it works also with it

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defninn}{Definition}

\newcounter{defcounter}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{defn}
 {\global\chardef\dc@currentequation=\value{equation}%
  \let\c@equation\c@defcounter
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{D\arabic{equation}}%
  % comment the following line if you don't use hyperref
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{D\arabic{equation}}%
  \defninn}
 {\enddefninn
  \setcounter{equation}{\dc@currentequation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Bla bla
\begin{equation}
x = y
\end{equation}

\begin{defn}
bla bla
\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
a = b
\end{equation}
\end{defn}

Bla bla
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eq:two}
\end{equation}

\begin{defn}
bla bla
\begin{gather}
x = yz \label{eq:ga} \\
a = b \label{eq:gb}
\end{gather}
\end{defn}

Bla bla
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

From equations \eqref{eq:one}~and~\eqref{eq:two} or
from equation~\eqref{eq:ga}, we deduce something.

\end{document}
```

[image]