# LaTeX locally change equation numbering in empheq

Tags: equations, numbering, empheq

The following short sample generates a list of numbered chemical reactions. I would like to change the numbering from the default (1) and (2) to (R1) and (R2).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[right=\quad\empheqrbrace \text{\ce{C-H} fission}]{align}
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH3CO + H} \\
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH2CHO + H}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

I tried using the technique given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184641/81179), shown below, changing what's given in the link to `align`, but it errors out reporting `Package keyval Error: reaction undefined.`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcounter{defcounter}
\setcounter{defcounter}{0}
\newenvironment{reaction}{%
\addtocounter{align}{-1}
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{R\thedefcounter}
\begin{align}}
{\end{align}}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[right=\quad\empheqrbrace \text{\ce{C-H} fission}]{reaction}
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH3CO + H} \\
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH2CHO + H}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please clarify what you are trying to do. Specifically, do you want ALL equations numbered as `(R1)`, `(R2)`, `...` or just some of them? If the latter, please say whether you want the numbering to look like `(1)`, `(2)`, `(R3)`, `(R4)`, `(5)`, `...`, or for the R-numbers to be independent of the other equation numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `empheq` package provides clever means to create nice equations. Using wrappers for some other setup requires some work to do (see section 6 *Creating something new* for examples and descriptions)

I've decided to use a special `reactempheq` environment which uses the common equation counter but applies the `(R1)` format. The usual `empheq` environment is not changed by this.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{reactempheq}[2][]{%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{R\arabic{equation}}
  \setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{#2}%
  \setkeys{EmphEqOpt}{#1}%
  \EmphEqMainEnv%
}{%
  \endEmphEqMainEnv%
}


\begin{reactempheq}[right=\quad\empheqrbrace \text{\ce{C-H} fission}]{align}
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH3CO + H} \\
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH2CHO + H}
\end{reactempheq}

\begin{empheq}[right=\quad\empheqrbrace \text{\ce{C-H} fission}]{align}
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH3CO + H} \\
\ce{CH3CHO &-> CH2CHO + H}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]