# How can I have two sets of numbering for formulas?

Tags: equations, hyperref, numbering

How can I have two sets of numbering for formulas in an article like the following:

(1) y=ax+b

(i) E=mc^2

(ii) S=r^2

(2) y=x^2

(iii) f(x):=4x

(3) abc

(4) bca

(5) cab

I have read answers to [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184637/5590). But I cannot adapt those codes to the case here since another set of numbering is only used in the "Definition" environment in the linked question; while in my question, I would like to  be able to switch between two sets of numbering whenever I want.

Comment: Using \tag you can even number them randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I defined an alternative equation counter, and use `\useoriginaleqn` and `\usealternateeqn` to switch between using either. The switch also updates the representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{altequation}
\let\c@equationstore\c@equation
\let\c@altequationstore\c@altequation
% Switch between different equation counters/representations
\newcommand{\useoriginaleqn}{%
  \let\c@equation\c@equationstore
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}}
\newcommand{\usealternateeqn}{%
  \let\c@equation\c@altequation
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}}
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{\def\theHequation{\theHsection.\theequation}}

\begin{document}

See the following equations: \eqref{eqn:first}, \eqref{eqn:second}, \eqref{eqn:third}, \eqref{eqn:fourth}

\begin{equation} y = ax + b \label{eqn:first} \end{equation}

\usealternateeqn

\begin{equation} E = mc^2 \label{eqn:second} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} S = r^2 \label{eqn:third} \end{equation}

\useoriginaleqn

\begin{equation} y = x^2 \label{eqn:fourth} \end{equation}

\usealternateeqn

\begin{equation} f(x) \vcentcolon= 4x \end{equation}

\useoriginaleqn

\begin{equation} abc \end{equation}

\begin{equation} bca \end{equation}

\begin{equation} cab \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: More work is required if this also has to work with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (and avoid duplicate hyperlink targets).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do use the package `hyperref`. Would you please elaborate a little bit regarding what should be done further?

Comment: @Jack: I've updated the answer to be compatible with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). The requirement is to update `\theHequation`.